# Angularjs, Best way to bind data to model from service in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

For example :

1. I have one search page for listing products, products data is huge fetched using service and i am trying to create dom element dynamically using directive, now i want to know what is the best way of binding data in view.
2. i have created using ng-repeat but, it is too slow to load the application.

Comment: Do you need to load the entire set? It is not possible to use pagination and load only a subset of your data, and get more results from the service when required?

Comment: I am using pagination, limiting to 10 records for every request, but i am facing problem while binding data to view. To fetch data from Server it took 0.035MS but to render in view it is taking 51.01Second.